# How can I bring my button to front

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a small button in triangle shape. However, it looks more like a 2-D shape and doesn't really have the feel of a button. Please look at my code below:

```
private String style = 
        "-fx-min-width: 10px; " +
        "-fx-min-height: 10px; " +
        "-fx-background-color: grey;";

Button btn = new Button();
btn.setShape(new Polygon(new double[]{
        0.0, 0.0,
        2.0, 3.0,
        0.0, 6.0
        }));

btn.setStyle(style);
btn.toFront();
```

How can I make it look more like a button rather than a flat 2D shape. Please note that I cannot increase the size of this button. Is there any alternative to make a small sized shape appear more like a button?

Comment: since, it's a button, how about adding a custom ImageIcon to it with .setIcon()?

Comment: @NickTritsis - yes, I had thought about it but I cannot do that since it would then not be consistent with other buttons in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's a matter of *styling*, `CSS` in particular more than `JavaFX`.
You can change the style of the button and keep the same shape (triangle).

For example if I apply this `CSS style` which I borrowed from [here](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/)

```
String style = 
            "-fx-background-color: "
            + "linear-gradient(#686868 0%, #232723 25%, #373837 75%, #757575 100%),"
            + "linear-gradient(#020b02, #3a3a3a),"
            + "linear-gradient(#9d9e9d 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #242424 100%),"
            + "linear-gradient(#8a8a8a 0%, #6b6a6b 20%, #343534 80%, #262626 100%),"
            + "linear-gradient(#777777 0%, #606060 50%, #505250 51%, #2a2b2a 100%);"
            + "-fx-background-insets: 0,1,4,5,6;"
            + "-fx-background-radius: 9,8,5,4,3;"
            + "-fx-padding: 15 30 15 30;" 
            + "-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(255,255,255,0.2) , 1, 0.0 , 0 , 1)";
```

And keeping your code:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setShape(new Polygon(new double[]{
                         0.0, 0.0,
                         2.0, 3.0,
                         0.0, 6.0}));                        
btn.setStyle(style);
```

It will give this style:

[image: some style]

While your original one is:

[image: original style]

Note that you can see other examples (styles) for buttons (kind of 3D) on that site (it's up to your preference).